# How can I delete a parent app.js item from a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter, react-hooks

By clicking the delete button I'm expecting to filter a parent app.js component array and delete a particular item. But I'm getting a Typescript error **Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: /src/components/TaskComponent.tsx: Identifier 'deleteTask' has already been declared.**, for I'm typing a handle delete as a prop. Also do I need to filter the main Tasks array twice, in the child and in the parent component ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-typescript-24-04-eg91s5?file=/src/components/TaskComponent.tsx

```js
// Child component

    import React, { useState, FC } from "react";

    type Tasks = {
      title: string;
      author: string;
      description: string;
      status: number | any;
      priority: number | any;
    };

    type Props = {
      Tasks: Tasks[];
      changeTask: (tasks: Tasks) => {};
      deleteTask: (id: Tasks) => {};
    };
    const TaskComponent: FC<Props> = ({ Tasks, changeTask, deleteTask }) => {
      
      const deleteTask = (id) => {
        Tasks.filter(task => task.id === id)
      };
      
      return (
      ...
      <input type="button" value="delete" onClick={deleteTask} />
      )
    }

    // App.js component

    const Tasks = [
      {
        id: "001",
        status: 0,
        priority: 2,
        title: "Develop website homepage",
        description:
          "Create a visually appealing and responsive homepage for the website",
        schedule: {
          creation_time: "2021-07-23T10:00:00"
        },
        author_name: "John Smith"
      },...
      }
    function App() {
      const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);
      
    const deleteTask = (id) => {
        setTasks((tasks) => tasks.filter((task) => task.id === id));
      };

return (
   <TaskComponent
              Tasks={tasks}
              changeTask={changeTask}
              deleteTaskP={deleteTask}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting issue would be that inside `App.tsx` you are passing a prop named `deleteTaskP` - a typo or was it your intention instead of `deleteTask` - which is what you seem to be expecting as prop in your Child component `TaskComponent` and instead would have a value of `undefined` (*destructuring non-existant property*), so modify `App.tsx`:

```
function App() {
// ...
return (
 <TaskComponent
     Tasks={tasks}
     changeTask={changeTask}
     // deleteTaskP={deleteTask}
     deleteTask={deleteTask}
 />
}
```

And then inside `TaskComponent` you are already expecting a prop named `deleteTask` and both trying to create a `deleteTask` of the similar functionality, so don't clash the names, but if you do need a new function then use a different name, remove that from `TaskComponent.tsx`:

```
const TaskComponent: FC<Props> = ({ Tasks, changeTask, deleteTask }) => {

 // Remove (or rename) this function and instead use 'deleteTask' prop
 // const deleteTask = (id) => {
 //  Tasks.filter(task => task.id === id)
 // };

return (...);
}
```

Additionally in your CodeSandbox I noticed your `type Tasks` has a wrong property name `author` instead of `author_name` inside the same `TaskComponent.tsx`:

```
type Tasks = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  // author: string; // make sure to rename into:
  author_name: string;
  description: string;
  status: number | any;
  priority: number | any;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the TaskComponent you pass deleteTask as a prop and then you declare variable with the same name inside of the TaskComponent. You cannot do that, just use different name if you need to preserve both.

You're destructuring your props, so basically `({deleteTask})` means `const deleteTask = ...` inside of the TaskComponent